# How to place multiple lines of code between an open and closing short-code

Tags: html, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I am trying to add multiple lines of code in a custom html page template between a shortcode that would restrict the content .

The short-code is:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[wcm_restrict plans="gold, platinum"]Restricted Content[/wcm_restrict]"); ?>
```

I have tried placing the code in the shortcode like below but with no luck:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[wcm_restrict plans="gold, platinum"]"); ?>
    <h1>This is a Heading for demo display</h1>
    <p>This is a demo paragraph.</p>
    <?php echo do_shortcode("[/wcm_restrict]"); ?>
```

What would the correct way be for placing multiple lines of code between the shortcode?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[wcm_restrict plans="gold, platinum"]Multiple lines of code here[/wcm_restrict]"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with your first approach is that your content is outside the shortcode and you're inserting two shortcodes.

Try something like this and let us know:

```
<?php

$content = '[wcm_restrict plans=\"gold, platinum\"]
    <h1>This is a Heading for demo display</h1>
    <p>This is a demo paragraph.</p>[/wcm_restrict]';

echo do_shortcode("$content"); ?>
```

**EDIT**: As pointed out by [rick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12195497/rick) the double quotes need to be escaped. The answer has been updated to reflect that change.

Comment: Hi thanks Lucas, no errors but its not displaying anything. and I did add a closing tag in the end "?>" and I even removed the shortcode "[wcm_restrict]" and it did not display any content.

Comment: after playing around with your code, we got it to work if stated like so ```<?php

    $content = '[wcm_restrict plans=\"gold, platinum\"]
    <h1>This is a Heading for demo display</h1>
    <p>This is a demo paragraph.</p>[/wcm_restrict]';
?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("$content"); ?>``` , please update your answer to that and I can mark your answer as the final answer pls and thanks for all your help